# gradle - Project 'customjrxml' not found in root project 'customjrxml'

Tags: java, gradle, build

i get below error while gradle build. Below is my build gradle and settings gradle files. help me to resolve it.

> org.gradle.execution.taskpath.ProjectFinderByTaskPath$ProjectLookupException:
> Project 'customjrxml' not found in root project 'customjrxml'.    at
> org.gradle.execution.taskpath.ProjectFinderByTaskPath.findProject(ProjectFinderByTaskPath.java:47)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskpath.TaskPathResolver.resolvePath(TaskPathResolver.java:49)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:96)

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
      println 'in repositories'
      dirs 'libs'
    }
}

configurations.create('jasperreports')
configurations.jasperreports {
 transitive = true
}
dependencies {
    jasperreports fileTree(dir: 'libs',include: '*.jar')
 }

task compileJasperJava {
    def jasperSourceDir = file('src/main/jasperreports')
    def jasperTargetDir = file('build/classes/main/jasperreports')
    
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'jrc', classname: 'net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask', classpath: configurations.jasperreports.asPath)
        jasperTargetDir.mkdirs()
        jrc(srcdir: jasperSourceDir, destdir:jasperTargetDir) {
            include(name:'**/*.jrxml')
        }
    }
}

classes.dependsOn compileJasperJava
```

## **settings.gradle:**

```
rootProject.name = 'customjrxml'
```

libs dir is having required jar files for jasper and apache commons logging.

Comment: is it ok when you put `include ':app'` in settings.gradle

Comment: Which version of Gradle? What is the command-line that causes the problem? I copied the info to this link and it seems to work OK (Gradle 5.6.1 and 6.7). You may want to pull and see if it works, as a sanity-check - https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64523134

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue is with gradle build command i have used. gradle project strucuture seems wrong, as of nowmodified gradle customjrxml:build to gradle build and it worked.